# Emulator - phone dial not working

Tags: android

I have set up an emulator through the AVD Manager. My applications are getting installed on the emulator.

However, I want to make a call from Emulator 1 to emulator 2. When I press the Call button - nothing is happening. Is there any issue. I have followed all instructions given in the android dev guide.

Note I'm using API Level 13 - is it disabled in this API OR some other problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Telneting to the emulator. 
Use a telnet app (like putty) and telnet to localhost at port 5554 (the number you see in your emulator).

Then type:

```
gsm call NUMBER
```

I'm not sure how you dial from one emulator to the other, though...
But you can try `gsm call 5556`... Maybe it would work